# Reasoning behind advantage of hash index/when should they be used over BTREE index?

Tags: database, indexing

I was debating between using BTREE index or HASH index.

**Theoretically, what are the advantages of using HASH indexes?**
**When should they be chosen and more importantly, why?**

I have read that hash indexes are good for point queries, but WHY?

I already know that BTREE indexes are best for range queries because you can easily traverse through the leaf nodes by going from left to right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention a specific DBMS so this answer is pretty generic.

A properly performing hash index should reach the answer to a point query in a single fetch.  A B-Tree will use something like lg_B(n) secondary storage accesses where B is the approximate branch factor and n is the number of entries.  Caching and reasonable node sizes will likely keep that to a couple of fetches but still twice that for the hash index.  In addition, each B-Tree access has non-trivial computations associated with it in order to traverse the sub-index in each node (something like lg_2(B) data comparison operations per node).  The computation time for a hash index is usually very limited (a hash computation and a small number of data comparison operations - hopefully one).  The computation time for searching within each node is often significant for B-Tree based indices.

In terms of picking, use a hash index if

- you only expect point queries
- you don't expect the data to fall into any poorly performing cases for the system hash function (oddball case but thought I should mention it)

B-Tree family are better if you have any kind of range query and/or want sorted results on a pre-determinable set of columns.